# Number of access happened on a file

Tags: linux

How to know the number of access happened on a file for a particular day.
example - I have emp.txt file.

I need to know the number access happened on the emp.txt file for a particular day.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Abu

Comment: Define "access"

Comment: how can we use it.

Comment: What have you already tried, or what are your searches efforts have been concentrated into ? Thanks to add this very important information by [editing your original post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49262242/edit)

Comment: @Fazil: what I meant was "you should elaborate on what you mean by access"

Comment: for example.  I'm using 'cat emp.txt' to see the content of the file.I need to know how many cat are happened on the file emp.txt in a particular day

Comment: for example.  I'm using 'cat emp.txt' to see the content of the file.I need to know how many cat are happened on the file emp.txt in a particular day

Comment: That's going to be tough especially if other users and/or processes access that file. But, if you just want to check how many times you've accessed it, you can probably "grep" your history.